# Telas Iniciais Dinamica

Tags: android, android-activity

Gostaria de criar algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Se(O banco de dados tiver tabela criada) {  
    Manter a Activity Principal;  
} Senão {  
    Abra Activity de criação da tabela;  
}
```

Resumindo, o android irá abrir a Activity principal e verificar o banco de dados, se tiver alguma tabela, mantenha a Activity principal, se não tiver nada, ele abre Activity para a criação da tabela.

Se tiver como verificar o banco de dados antes de abrir qualquer Activity com alguma Splash Screens, por exemplo uma tela com um progress bar, pode ser. Fica até mais legal na minha opnião. 
Acho que ficou fácil de entender o meu propósito.

Comment: Não necessita de usar `<br>` para fazer quebra de linha. Use a barra de espaços duas vezes e faça *enter*. Para mais informação sobre formatação siga este [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica @ramaral

Answer (score 0):

para verificar se um banco de dados existe você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
public static boolean doesDatabaseExist(ContextWrapper context, String dbName) {
File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
return dbFile.exists();
```

}

para verificar se a tabela existe você pode criar um método do banco de dados no qual verifica se existe a tabela e seu retorno é booleano e coloca a validação no if.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia fazer assim para verificar se a tabela existe

```
public boolean existeTabela(String tableName, boolean openDb) {
    if(openDb) {
        if(myDataBase == null || !myDataBase.isOpen()) {
            myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
        }

        if(!myDataBase.isReadOnly()) {
            myDataBase.close();
            myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT table_name from sqlite_master where table_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Estou terminando algumas outras partes e farei os testes no seu código. Obrigado! @EDIT Poderia colocar comentários sobre o que cada código faz, algumas coisas eu tenho ideia do que faz, outras não, comecei a programar no android faz menos de uma semana, to meio perdido ainda.